# Mass replacement on a plain text file

Tags: notepad++, replace

My data looks like this:

**7DigitNumbers**(tabspace)**IRRELEVANTSTUFF123**(tabspace)**30**

example:

```
2712061    really irrelevant words and numbers     30
```

What I'm trying to get is:

**7DigitNumbers**(tabspace)**30**

on the same example:

```
2712061     30
```

I've tried several combinations on notepad++ via find&replace function, but couldn't figure it out. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance,
Mit

Comment: Can you open it in Excel as a CSV file and delimit based upon Tab?

Comment: The problem is that "the irrelevant stuff" contains random tabspace characters, making it useless on excel. I need the equivalent of NUMBERS(tabspace)TOTALLYRANDOM(tabspace)30

Comment: Is this question off-topic? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Anish Gupta: Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic as per the FAQ.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I've heard of that but it sounds like it would be better to have this in superuser

Answer (score 1):

Get a copy of awk for windows eg: [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and use the following command: `awk "{print $1,$NF}"`. This prints the first and last column (NF is number of fields).

A quick test replicating your data into a file and adding some tabs between some of the words yields:

```
C:\temp>awk "{print $1 \"\t\" $NF}" z.dat
2712061 32
2712062 31
2712063 30
```

The awk print statement concatenates all its arguments - so this will separate the values from the first and last columns with a single tab character.

Comment: Notepad++ can be extended with true RegEx functionality using the PythonScript Notepad++ plugin and my script below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Don Ho added RegEx backtracking to the Notepad++ native replace.
Download Notepad 6.1.1 from [here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.1.html)
Install Notepad 6.1.1, then go to Search->Replace on

```
Find what:    ^([0-9]{7})(\t).*([0-9]{2})$  
Replace with: \1\2\3
```

Click on the Replace All button

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) Notepad++ plugin for Python Regular Expression search and replace.
See [here](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html#Editor.pyreplace) for functions

```
Editor.pyreplace(search, replace[, count[, flags[, startLine[, endLine]]]])
```

and

```
Editor.pymlreplace(search, replace[, count[, flags[, startPosition[, endPosition]]]])
```

Here's a simple program using the python Regular Expression search and replace function editor.pyreplace()
I've left lots of debug code in so you can see what is happening during the course of the function run.

```
# $Revision: 1.3 $
# $Author: dot $
# $Date: 2012/04/19 00:03:26 $

from Npp import *
import re, string

expression = notepad.prompt(
                 "Enter the search string on the first line, followed by Ctrl+Enter, \n" +
                 "followed by the replace string on second line",
                 "RegEx and Search/Replace" ,
                 "")

debug = True
#debug = False

if debug:
    bufferID = notepad.getCurrentBufferID()

if debug:
    # Show console for debugging
    console.clear()
    console.show()

if expression != None:
    expressionList = re.split(r"[\n\r]+", expression)

    if debug:
        console.write( expression + "\n" )

    if len(expressionList) == 2:
        if debug:
            console.write( "'" + expressionList[0] + "', '" + expressionList[1] + "'\n" )

        # First we'll start an undo action, then Ctrl-Z will undo the actions of the whole script
        editor.beginUndoAction()

        if debug:
            console.write( 'editor.pyreplace( r"%s" % expressionList[0], r"%s" % expressionList[1], 0, re.IGNORECASE)\n' )

        editor.pyreplace( r"%s" % expressionList[0], r"%s" % expressionList[1], 0, re.IGNORECASE)

        # End the undo action, so Ctrl-Z will undo the above two actions
        editor.endUndoAction()

# Debug
if debug:
    notepad.activateBufferID(bufferID)
```

After you have this script linked to a Notepad++ shortcut (i.e. Ctrl+r), search on

```
^([0-9]{7})(\t).*([0-9]{2})$
```

and replace with

```
\1\2\3
```

Map this script to Notepad++ shortcut `Ctrl+<ChooseALetter>` and run it.
I've tested this script and it works great!

Comment: Why not just use the [built in](http://www.slideshare.net/anjesh/the-power-of-regular-expression-use-in-notepad/) regex find/replace?

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt  ... Ummm, because it does not support regular expression backreferences.

Comment: It has backreferences in the slides I linked.

Comment: OK RegEx {} are not supported. {} are kind of important here where the first 7 digits and the last 2 digits need to be returned. Try doing a Notepad++ native replace with Find string "^([0-9]{7})(\t).*([0-9]{2})$" and Replace string \1\2\3 with the Regular expression option selected. You'll get result "0 occurrences were replaced." Doesn't work. My script works.

Comment: That would make sense. I've got Notepad++ v5.9.8 Unicode.
Looks like Don Ho released a new version on Mar 26. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt Does the RegEx OR opeartor | work in Notepad++ 6.1.1?